# vuejs - <slot> in repeating table row

Tags: javascript, components, vue.js, vue-component

im using this solution to set table cells in a vuejs component dynamically:

http://forum.vuejs.org/topic/526/repeating-table-row-with-slot

This works just with Vue.js v1.0.10 but not with the current version v1.0.26.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/peL8fuz3/

I'm trying to get the following markup (the item object should be available in the component)

```
<div id="vue">
    <basic-table>
        <table-cell>{{ item.id }}</table-cell>
        <table-cell>{{ item.title }}</table-cell>
    </basic-table>
</div>
```

Vue.js component (more at the fiddle)

```
Vue.component('basic-table', {
    template: '<table><tbody><tr v-for="item in collection" v-slot></tr></tbody></table>',
    data: function () {
        return {
            collection: [
                {id: 1, title: 'Vue'},
                {id: 2, title: 'Vue 2'},
                {id: 3, title: 'Vue 3'},
                {id: 4, title: 'Vue 4'},
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?

**Edit**
Didnt found a working solution yet - still searching..

Comment: You could just not use a slot and pass the cell data to the table-cell component as a prop. In the current version of vue I think the slot directive is just slot not v-slot but both might be accepted

Comment: check the jsfiddle - there is a slot - directive defined :)

Comment: The template in VueJS is actually not HTML, it is representing of a render function wrapped into syntax sugar which is very similar to a real HTML. That's why you must have td inside tr and li inside ul.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quite hard to find out what exactly gone wrong, but that code was broken since *v1.0.18*. I was unable to dig deeper to eliminate exact commit but there was a couple of optimizations made which potentially could affect `$context._content` rendering.

#### Solution

However you can solve your problem by changing

```
var raw = host.$options._content;
```

to

```
var raw = host._context._directives.filter(function (value) {
    return !(value.Component === undefined);
})[0].el;
```

That change is compatible with *v1.0.26*. You can find fixed code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7v1f93d6/).

#### Disclaimer

I was failed to find a way to achieve the same result using public API. So this solution is also relies on non-public API thus may break in future release.

Comment: thanks! but this solution ia not dynamic enough, didnt work e.x. if i got more data :/

Comment: @Aaroniker do you mean more directives?

Comment: i just tried it at my application, didnt worked so far, going to dump the data tomorrow to find out whats going wrong :)

Comment: @Aaroniker seems I know where is a problem. I'll update my answer

Comment: @Aaroniker unfortunately I found that searching for correct directive in `_directives` array may be quite painful. I'll write back once I found good solution. Could you please also give me a minimal example which fails with provided solution?

Comment: @Aaroniker: seems I finally found an approach. I've updated my answer. here is your last example with latest fix https://jsfiddle.net/gu5pfbof/

Comment: this works, but not with the minified version of vuejs: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js - but why? :D

Comment: (if i also include jquery)

Comment: @Aaroniker I guess that's because private api became renamed by minifier. I'll see if it's possible to work around it

Comment: i've tried some workarounds, but cant find a solution :/

Comment: @Aaroniker same here :( The problem is not in minifier, but in _different behavior_ between full and minified versinon. still searching for a solution

Comment: @Aaroniker well.. Sorry, but I failed to find out reilable solution :( it seems to me, that it's better to address this issuse to vue developers since they have deeper understanding of framewok.

Answer (score 2):

Aaron, my answer probably is not satisfied for your question but why don't you make it simple as the following code but you have to use directive and all of this stuff ?

I am still figuring why your solution is working on the previous version, not the current version. :D

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#vue',
  data: {
    items: [{
      id: 1,
      title: 'Vue'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Vue 2'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      title: 'Vue 3'
    }, {
      id: 4,
      title: 'Vue 4'
    }, ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" class="table" id="vue">
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="item in items">
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>{{item.title}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: because the component "basic-table" is more complex at my application - i just want to define the table cells dynamically - so the item object should be available in `<basic-table>`

Comment: @trungk If it helps, it appears that raw.children.length = 0 on the newer version

Comment: Sorry Aaron I still didn't find the solution but @vsminkov seem did.